# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using smtp protocol to send mails using mailtrap. It is working perfectly in localhost but it is giving error.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Type error: Too
>   few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(),
>   0 passed in
>   public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php
>   on line 88 and exactly 1 expected

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=name
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

mail.php

```
<?php
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525,
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: You shouldn't post your credentials in a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thanks Morgan Lane

Comment: try this in mail `'driver' => 'smtp'`,

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: try `php artisan vendor:publish` and `composer dump-autoload `

Comment: its is perfectly working on localhost .but in live server it giving this error

Comment: make a try this command on server

Comment: Still doesn't work.....

Answer (score 1):

First: Make Sure that you have mail.php and services.php in config folder set

with the following respectively:

mail.php

```
 <?php
    return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525,
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

And services.php (note that this includes the mailgun configuration)

```
<?php

return [

'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],

'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
],

'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
],

'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],

];
```

**ADD THIS ON YOUR boostrap/app/php file**

```
$app->configure('mail'); // this is to configure the mail
$app->configure('services'); // and to configure the services
//$con = env('MAIL_DRIVER');

// dd($con);

dd(config('mail')); // this is to print the mail configuration so you can know what mail configuration are being read.

return $app;
```

run `php artisan serve` within the terminal
just to see the contents of the mail configuration.

**PLEASE NOTE**
    I Noticed that the simple fix is to just UPDATE/MODIFY THE .env file with the credentials(using gmail smtp server as example)

```
MAIL_DRIVER_=smtp  (instead of MAIL_DRIVER, update it the mail.php)
MAIL_HOST_=smtp.gmail.com (instead of MAIL_HOST)
MAIL_PORT_=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=
MAILGUN_SECRET=
```

After that, if you were already running your server. Kill it and rerun it again. This should solve your errors,

**REASON**

For reasons I couldn't explain, some of the mail config parameter didn't reflect until I applied the change above.

Secondly I later changed the .env settings to the original name eliminating the extra "_" as well as updated the mail.php, and had to kill the already running server and rerun it again before it reflected and ran well or worked!.

Hope this helps